# TestLinkAPIClient cannot be resolved to a type, already I added "testlink-java-api" dependency in maven, language used is java

Tags: selenium, appium, testlink

TestLinkAPIClient cannot be resolved to a type, already I added “testlink-java-api” dependency in pom.xml.
Its maven project by using java
please find the below code

```
package com.tesco.pom.baseClass;

import br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPIException;

public class ExecuteTestLinkResults implements TestLinkIntegration {

    public static void reportTestCaseResult(String Project, String TestPlan, 

String TestCase, String Build, String notes, String teststatus) throws TestLinkAPIException {

    TestLinkAPIClient testlinkAPIClient = new TestLinkAPIClient(APIKEY, URL);

    testlinkAPIClient.reportTestCaseResult(Project, TestPlan, TestCase, Build, notes, 

    teststatus);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestLinkAPIClient does not provide any Maven dependency because it is a third party tool.
So you have to download and add jar files for that you can follow this link:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/dbfacade-testlink-rpc-api/downloads

Download "testlink-api-client-2.0.tar.gz" and import this jar file and start doing your work.

If you still want jar as Maven dependency then you can try and install jar files by following this link:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I added jars in normal Hybrid framework, not in maven